# Is there free wifi in Sydney Airport?

Tags: australia, wifi, sydney, syd

I'm flying into Sydney airport in about a week, and there's a chance that I'll find myself wanting to look online for a [last minute hotel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10931/are-there-websites-which-do-last-minute-accomodation-deals-in-australia). However, because I will just have arrived, I won't have had a chance to go and get an Australian SIM card.

Is there wifi available in Sydney Airport? And if so, is it free or paid-for? I'm particularly interested in the arrivals side for this, but information on departures side would be good for the future too!

Comment: Won't bother adding another answer, but will point out I was there 6 weeks ago and used it just fine - totally free, and is accessible on both arrivals and departures side.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, at T1 (International Terminal) and T2 (Domestic Terminal).

I was there in 2011 but can't remember the details (except that I *did* use internet connection at the airport). Anyway, [Foursquare](https://foursquare.com/v/t1-international-terminal/4aeb45caf964a5206cc021e3) is a good memory aid, and several tips from 2011 and 2012 say there's indeed wifi available.

[February 10, 2012](https://foursquare.com/item/4f3471a6e4b0c78d28f7ddc2):

> Free wifi all over with the "FREE WIFI BY EXPEDIA SYD" network. Just
>   choose a destination and flight number.

[August 24, 2012](https://foursquare.com/item/5036db6be4b0be420e6bddb9):

> You get free and fast wifi here!

[March 11, 2011](https://foursquare.com/item/4d796d27c307a35de5644431):

> Free wifi in the international terminal (T1)

[October 2, 2012](https://foursquare.com/item/506aafc5e4b01151fafa26b0):

> Aquí el wifi gratis funciona!!!

**Update**: The [Sydney airport website](http://www.sydneyairport.com.au/find/service-categories/service-listing/service-detail.aspx?cat=%7B613DC877-71E1-4C1A-9B3F-A610DA97F416%7D&ser=%7BBA29FD32-5CAC-4A44-B723-322AE4529405%7D) also confirms this:

> **Free Wi-Fi is available throughout International Terminal (T1) and
>   Domestic Terminal (T2)**.
>
> Sydney Airport now provides free Wi-Fi for all travellers at both the
>   Domestic (T2) and International (T1) Terminals. You can use any Wi-Fi
>   enabled device to connect including your laptop, smartphone or tablet.
>
> Simply select “Free Internet by sponsors name & SYD” from the list of
>   available networks, answer the questions, read the terms and
>   conditions and click "Proceed". You will be shown a sponsored message
>   then directed to a website.
>
> From there you can browse the internet for up to 2 hours and 500MB of
>   data.
>
> Coverage is provided throughout the entire International Terminal (T1)
>   and Domestic Terminal (T2).

Comment: (Elsewhere in Sydney, in restaurants and bars, I found wifi to be a rarity. Quite a contrast to Argentina, where I was coming from, where most restaurants and even ice cream shops etc had free wifi.)

Comment: Weird - here in Brisbane virtually every public park and government building has wifi, as well as trains and some busses. Most cafes do to. Must be a Sydney thing!

Comment: Worth noting that my experiences were from 2011, things might have changed since then.

Answer (score 5):

Wifi is free at Sydney International and domestic airport. 
Please refrain from providing any sensitive information for signup. Simply type in a name in a name field and abcd@abcd.com in email field. In this way you can avoid getting marketing emails. Choose meeter/greeter in purpose of visit field. In this way most of the time they won't ask for the same particulars again when you re-sign whenever you are disconnected.

On Android devices most of the time the sign up only once.. On iOS devices its required every time.

Answer (score 4):

Based on Jonik's answer, I went and did some more googling. I eventually found a [Free Wifi page on the airport website](http://www.sydneyairport.com.au/find/service-categories/service-listing/service-detail.aspx?cat=%7B3ED445B5-0AA5-4D0A-9B66-68C70DBE52C2%7D&ser=%7BBA29FD32-5CAC-4A44-B723-322AE4529405%7D)

> Free Wi-Fi is available throughout International Terminal (T1) and Domestic Terminal (T2).
>
> Sydney Airport now provides free Wi-Fi for all travellers at both the Domestic (T2) and International (T1) Terminals. You can use any Wi-Fi enabled device to connect including your laptop, smartphone or tablet.
>
> Simply select “Free Internet by sponsors name & SYD” from the list of available networks, answer the questions, read the terms and conditions and click "Proceed". You will be shown a sponsored message then directed to a website.
>
> From there you can browse the internet for up to 2 hours and 500MB of data. Coverage is provided throughout the entire International Terminal (T1) and Domestic Terminal (T2).

So, looks like I should be able to get enough free wifi to find a hotel if I need one, and there'll also be some for when waiting to fly out again!

Comment: Btw, I expanded my answer an hour ago to include the exact same info from airport website :)

Comment: (Also, you can insert that link just fine with the 'insert hyperlink' button; it gets escaped so that it works. See my edit.)